# how to insert the data into the table dynamically in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display the result of an exam in a table, suppose I taken the test for one paper that result should be display in first row of table layout panel and if I taken test for one more paper that result should be display in second row of table layout panel dynamically using c# (if i click on store result button it should redirect to test result form and display the result)

```
 public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private string papId;
    private string subject;
    private string chapter;
    private string tstname;

    public Form3(string papId,string tech,string subject,string chapter, string tstname,int maxMarks,int marksObtained)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.papId=papId;
        this.subject=subject ;
        this.chapter = chapter;
        this.tstname = tstname;
        int row = dsplyUserReslt.Count;
        Label lblTech = getLabelDetails();
        lblTech.Text = tech;
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lblTech, 0, row-1);
        Label lblSub = getLabelDetails();
        lblSub.Text = subject;
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lblSub,1, row-1);
        Label lblChptr = getLabelDetails();
        lblChptr.Text = chapter;
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lblChptr, 2, row-1);
        Label lbltstName = getLabelDetails();
        lbltstName.Text = tstname;
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lbltstName, 3, row-1);
        Label lblmaxmarks = getLabelDetails();
        lblmaxmarks.Text = maxMarks.ToString();
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lblmaxmarks, 4, row-1);
        Label lblmarksobtnd = getLabelDetails();
        lblmarksobtnd.Text = marksObtained.ToString();
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(lblmarksobtnd, 5, row - 1);
        Label date = getLabelDetails();
        date.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy");
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(date, 6, row - 1);
        Button btnImproveScore = new Button();
        btnImproveScore.Text = "improve score";
        btnImproveScore.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(135, 25);
        btnImproveScore.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
        dsplyUserReslt.Controls.Add(btnImproveScore, 7, row - 1);
        btnImproveScore.Click+=new EventHandler(this.btnImproveScore_Click);
      if (row > 4)
        { dsplyUserReslt.RowCount = 4; }
        else
        {
            dsplyUserReslt.RowCount = dsplyUserReslt.RowCount + 1;
            dsplyUserReslt.RowStyles.Clear();
            dsplyUserReslt.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 120F));
        }


    }
   public Label getLabelDetails()
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.AutoSize = true;
        lbl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12);
        lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        return lbl;
    }
```

Comment: And, where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: SO is not a software writing service... there's little doubt that this question will be closed in due course.

Comment: @MegaTron i taken the tabel layout panel as dsplyUsrReslt and initally its row count is 1. now my problem is if i taken the test for second time means again it is redirecting and it is displaing the row count value 1

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataGridView` and `DataTable`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
            dt.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "a" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "b" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "c" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "d" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, "e" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
​
​
```

Comment: if i taken the test for second time means again new data table will create i dont want like that it should be display in previous table only

Comment: I moved the definition of the DataTable to global memory so you don't recreate the DataTable each time code is called.

Comment: store result button is present in one form and when i click on that button i have display the result table in next form ,even we write data table in global memory also it will execute

Comment: Posted new Answer with a sample of my two form project.

Answer (score 1):

when working with multiple forms you must use an instance of the form and a helper function to move data between forms.  See my sample code below

Form 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 form2;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form2 = new Form2(this);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.Show();
            string results = form2.GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 form1;
        public Form2(Form1 nform1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form2_FormClosing);
            form1 = nform1;
            form1.Hide();
        }
        private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //stops for from closing
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Hide();
        }
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
        }

    }
}
```